# Unit testing the output of $sce.trustAsHtml in Angular

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am writing a REST app in Angular and I want to write unit tests for it (of course!). I have a controller which gets a list of blog posts from a REST service in json and puts the summaries into the $scope, so I can display them in the view.

At first the blog posts were just displaying as text ie `<p>Blog body</p>`, rather than rendering as parsed HTML, until I discovered that you can use [ng-bind-html](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml) in conjunction with the [$sce service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce). This now works fine in terms of displaying the blog posts correctly.

The problem arises when unit testing. I am trying to mock a json response with some HTML and then test that my controller is correctly dealing with the HTML. Here is my code:

### Controller

```
.controller( 'HomeCtrl', function HomeController( $scope, $http, $sce ) {
    $scope.posts = {};
    $http.get('../drupal/node.json').success(function (data) {
        var posts;
        posts = data.list;

        for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i ++) {
            posts[i].previewText = $sce.trustAsHtml(posts[i].body.summary);
            posts[i].created = posts[i].created + '000'; // add milliseconds so it can be properly formatted 
        }
        $scope.posts = posts;
    });
})
```

### unit test

```
describe('HomeCtrl', function() {
    var $httpBackend, $rootScope, $sce, createController;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        // Set up the mock http service responses
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

        $sce = $injector.get('$sce');

        createController = function() {
            return $controller('HomeCtrl', {
                '$scope': $rootScope
            });
        };
    }));

    it('should get a list of blog posts', function() {
        var rawResponse = {
            "list": [
                {
                    "body": {
                        "value": "\u003Cp\u003EPost body.\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
                        "summary": "\u003Cp\u003ESummary.\u003C\/p\u003E\n"
                    },
                    "created": "1388415860"
                }
            ]};
        var processedResponse = [{
                "body": {
                    "value": "\u003Cp\u003EPost body.\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
                    "summary": "\u003Cp\u003ESummary.\u003C\/p\u003E\n"
                },
                "created": "1388415860000",
            previewText: $sce.trustAsHtml("\u003Cp\u003ESummary.\u003C\/p\u003E\n")
        }];

        $httpBackend.when('GET', '../drupal/node.json').respond(rawResponse);
        $httpBackend.expectGET("../drupal/node.json").respond(rawResponse);
        var homeCtrl = createController();
        expect(homeCtrl).toBeTruthy();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($rootScope.posts).toEqual(processedResponse);
    });
});
```

When I run the above through the Karma test runner, I get the following response:

```
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows) home section HomeCtrl should get a list of blog posts FAILED
    Expected [ { body : { value : '<p>Post body.</p>
    ', summary : '<p>Summary.</p>
    ' }, created : '1388415860000', previewText : { $$unwrapTrustedValue : Function } }          ] to equal [ { body
: { value : '<p>Post body.</p>
    ', summary : '<p>Summary.</p>
    ' }, created : '1388415860000', previewText : { $$unwrapTrustedValue : Function } }     ].
```

I suspect the problem is due to the fact that `$sce.trustAsHtml` returns an object containing a function, rather than a string.

My question is, firstly, **am I approaching this problem in the correct way?**

Secondly, if so, **how should I go about testing the output of `$sce.trustAsHtml`?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since the answer given by michael-bromley didn't work for me I want to point out another solution. In my case I was using a filter that wraps each occurrence of a string in another string with a span that has a class of 'highlight'. In other words, I want words to be highlighted. Here is the code:

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
    return function (input, str) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml((input || '').replace(new RegExp(str, 'gi'), '<span class=\"highlighted\">$&</span>'));
    };
});
```

I use the $sce service to trust the resulting value as HTML. To test this I need to use the $$unwrapTrustedValue function on the resulting value to get my test working:

```
it('01: should add a span with class \'highlight\' around each mathing string.', inject(function ($filter) {
    // Execute
    var result = $filter('highlight')('this str contains a str that will be a highlighted str.', 'str');

    // Test
    expect(result.$$unwrapTrustedValue()).toEqual('this <span class="highlighted">str</span> contains a <span class="highlighted">str</span> that will be a highlighted <span class="highlighted">str</span>.'); 
}));
```

**UPDATE:**

As @gugol kindly pointed out it is preferred not to use Angular internal methods like $$unwrapTrustedValue. A better approach is to use the public getTrustedHtml method on the $sce service. Like so:

```
it('01: should add a span with class \'highlight\' around each mathing string.', inject(function ($sce, $filter) {
    // Execute
    var result = $filter('highlight')('this str contains a str that will be a highlighted str.', 'str');

    // Test
    expect($sce.getTrustedHtml(result)).toEqual('this <span class="highlighted">str</span> contains a <span class="highlighted">str</span> that will be a highlighted <span class="highlighted">str</span>.');
}));
```

Comment: This seems like a very clean way to do it, and the selected answer didn't work for me but this one did.  ;)

Comment: Looks like this has the consensus of being the better answer, so I'll mark it accordingly.

Comment: While this method works, using $$ prefixed properties/functions is not recommended. You're using undocumented and prone to change internal functionality of angular.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was something I also learned over time. Please post the correct answer if you have one?

Comment: nice - this approach works for $sce.trustAsResourceUrl too - thanks

Comment: `expect($sce.getTrustedHtml(result).toEqual('this <span class="highlighted">str</span> contains a <span class="highlighted">str</span> that will be a highlighted <span class="highlighted">str</span>.');`

Comment: Nice of the Angular doc folks to highlight `$sce.trustAsHtml()` (which returns an object) instead of `$sce.getTrustedHtml()`. Thanks for this answer, it worked for me too.

Answer (score 20):

You have to disable $sce using its provider before each test.

When $sce is disabled all $sce.trust* methods just return original value instead of a wrapper function.

```
beforeEach(module(function ($sceProvider) {
  $sceProvider.enabled(false);
}));

it('shall pass', inject(function($sce){
  expect($sce.trustAsHtml('<span>text</span>')).toBe('<span>text</span>');
}));
```

In your particular example just do this:

```
describe('HomeCtrl', function() {
  var $httpBackend, $rootScope, $sce, createController;

  beforeEach(module(function ($sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
  }));

  // rest of the file
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I added this to my failing tests and suddenly I had all passing tests.

Comment: My tests were failing with "Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context." even though actual implementation worked without issue. 

This answer lets me keep using the framework as intended, without changing implementation or using undocumented/private internals of angular.

This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

I discovered that you can use [`$sce.getTrusted`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce#methods_gettrusted) which will return the value originally passed to `$sce.trustAsHtml`, in this case a string containing HTML, which you can then test for equality in the usual way.

So my test now looks like this:

```
it('should create a previewText property using $sce.trustAsHtml', function() {
    // confirms that it is an object, as should be the case when 
    // it has been through $sce.trustAsHtml
    expect(typeof result.previewText === 'object').toEqual(true);

    expect($sce.getTrusted($sce.HTML, result.previewText))
      .toEqual('<p>Original HTML content string</p>');
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I used the $$unwrapTrustedValue function on the result to test my result. See my answer for details.

Comment: You can also use the shorthand `getTrustedHtml` when getting your original value in the test. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#getTrustedHtml

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the getTrustedHtml() function to get the html string value from $$unwrapTrustedValue.

```
vm.user.bio = $sce.getTrustedHtml(vm.user.bio);
```