# How to get unwrapped value of object that wrapped with $sce?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my web application I given an object that is wrapped with angular $sce.In this object each property has a special property $$unwrappedTrusted  but it doesn't really give me the object value.How I can get trusted value of object property?

Comment: Just a simple `.toString()` will give you the object value/.

Answer (score 22):

As @rrhrg said properties start with $$ considered as private and not safe to use. Better use valueOf method of $sce service.

```
var trustedResource = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("www.abcd.com/folder/image.png");
$sce.valueOf(trustedResource); // "www.abcd.com/folder/image.png"
```

http://jsbin.com/morixekuxi/edit?html,js,console

Comment: There is no such thing as `$sce.valueOf`.

Comment: Updated my answer. Added demo link

Comment: Since I still do not see such method in documentation, then it seems, that using `$sce.getTrustedResourceUrl` is more correct.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the getTrustedHtml() function. This gets the html string value from $$unwrapTrustedValue.

```
vm.user.bio = $sce.getTrustedHtml(vm.user.bio);
```

You may also need to include [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize).

There are more answers on this topic in this post:
[Unit testing the output of $sce.trustAsHtml in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946418/unit-testing-the-output-of-sce-trustashtml-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

I get value of each property by calling toString() function but I did not found any method that help me to find object itself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to unwrap (or use?) a value wrapped by angular's service `$sec`.

To use such a value in your html document, you can use the directive `ng-bind-html`.

```
<div ng-bind-html="myWrappedValue"></div>
```

To unwrap such a value, you may use the function `$$unwrapTrustedValue()`.

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('&copy;').$$unwrapTrustedValue() === '&copy;'
```

**Please note** that properties which start with two dollar signs ($$) are considered as private and should **NOT** be accessed!

See also http://jsfiddle.net/rrhrg/9vzckoj8/